# Why doesn't my setInterval function run more than once?

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, reload

I don't know why my function is not properly called every 100 milliseconds.
It is just called once, when the page is loaded/reloaded.
I am out of ideas what to try.

```js
var unit = document.getElementsByClassName('unit');
var date = new Date();

function setTime() {
  hour.textContent = date.getHours();
  unit[0].textContent = "h";
  minute.textContent = date.getMinutes();
  unit[1].textContent = "m";

  console.log('boom');
}

setInterval(setTime, 100);
```

```html
<h1 id="time">
  <span id="hour"></span><!-- 
  --><span class="unit"></span> 
  <span id="minute"></span><!-- 
  --><span class="unit"></span>
</h1>
```

Comment: You should get familiar with console logging and browser debugging. It would've taken a few seconds to see that your function _is_ running repeatedly, and that your date isn't being updated. See the revised snippet above.